# Get new object added to array in javascript after componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I get the new object added to an array after componentDidUpdate?

I have this two objects in prevProps:

```
objArray1 = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "abc",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "def",
    }
]
```

and I get this three objects in this.props

```
objArray2 = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "abc",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "def",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "ghi",
    }
]
```

and I want to get at the object that changed

```
newObject ={
            "id": 3,
            "name": "ghi",
        }
```

so that I can pass it to another function

Comment: Is just one object added at a time, or multiples objects can be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Set of `id` values from the `prevProps` with `Array.map()`, and filter out the new `props` that has an `id` that exists in the Set:

```js
const prevProps = [{"id":1,"name":"abc"},{"id":2,"name":"def"}]
const props = [{"id":1,"name":"abc"},{"id":2,"name":"def"},{"id":3,"name":"ghi"}]

const prevSet = new Set(prevProps.map(o => o.id))

const added = props.filter(o => !prevSet.has(o.id))

console.log(added)
```

If new items are *always added to the end of the array*, you can use `Array.slice()` to remove the previous items (the length of `prevProps), and get the new items:

```js
const prevProps = [{"id":1,"name":"abc"},{"id":2,"name":"def"}]
const props = [{"id":1,"name":"abc"},{"id":2,"name":"def"},{"id":3,"name":"ghi"}]

const added = props.slice(prevProps.length)

console.log(added)
```

Comment: Using `Set` is a nice idea +1, saves extra looping

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `objArray2` with id

```
 objArray2.filter(ele=> !objArray1.some(value=> value.id === ele.id) )
```

If extra items are always added after the previous object you can slice

```
   objArray2.slice(objArray1.length,)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the IDs increment by one each time they're added. Then you could store the latest id and check for greater ones on update.

Comment: I can do this but this is not safe... If something in my backend changes, then the code will not work anymore